# Android duplicate resources error

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources, android-vectordrawable

My project was compiling fine until I deleted some png drawables and replaced them with vector drawables by navigating to **New > Vector Asset**. I am now getting a **duplicate resources error**.

Here is my res folder:

[image]

Here is the error message in the Gradle console:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [drawable/ic_menu_manage] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_menu_manage.xml [drawable/ic_menu_manage] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/values/drawables.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable/ic_menu_share] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_menu_share.xml   [drawable/ic_menu_share] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/values/drawables.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable/ic_menu_slideshow] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_menu_slideshow.xml   [drawable/ic_menu_slideshow] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/values/drawables.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable/ic_menu_send] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_menu_send.xml [drawable/ic_menu_send] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/values/drawables.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable/ic_menu_gallery] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_menu_gallery.xml   [drawable/ic_menu_gallery] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/values/drawables.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable/ic_menu_camera] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_menu_camera.xml [drawable/ic_menu_camera] /Users/tomfinet/AndroidStudioProjects/Birthpay/app/src/main/res/values/drawables.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

How do I fix this and why is it happening?

Comment: Rebuild the project.

Comment: Clean & Rebuild your project and then run

Comment: Not working fellas

Comment: Guys, what is the problem here? @Onkar Nene

Comment: try to change the icon names. this might solve your pb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests that the `drawable.xml` file is responsible for the error. So I opened it and commented out the xml code and the app ran fine. I have no idea why this fixes it but this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

when we add some new thing in out project, in that case some times resources might get duplicate that time it will give the error while run the app, in my case also get same issue I had face, while I had added the kotlin activity in java project, in it gives me error

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. ...\themes.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

**so in this case please check the local history and remove the duplicate resources from res folder, so simply revert that changes**

**To revert changes click on res folder and go to local history and check the duplicate file name and revert that changes which was not present in running code**

[image]

**in my case there was \themes.xml file is added newly so I reverted that changes and run code, it run successfully**